# Как реализовать листание в боте для Telegram

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Просьба, подскажите куда копать.
Пытаюсь реализовать задачу наподобие бота [@entrytodoctorBot](https://t.me/entrytodoctorBot).
Очень заинтересовала реализация функционала, а именно:

1. листание данных назад и вперед без дополнительного вывода
2. вставка данных в нужное место- inlinebutton "получить расписание"

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: вы имеете ввиду такое? http://i.imgur.com/eY8Sw6A.png

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42874286/5000805

Answer (score 2):

Вообще говоря, такая прокрутка реализуется редактированием кнопок у сообщения
при нажатии на стрелку.

Когда обрабатываете обратный вызов по нажатии на кнопку пролистывания,
используйте метод [editMessageReplyMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagereplymarkup), чтобы изменить разметку кнопок
под сообщением.  Предварительно надо организовать клавиатуру таким образом,
чтобы y листающих кнопок в полях `callback_data` был бы закодирован номер
страницы, которую следует открыть.

Это вкратце. К сожалению, более точно ответ будет зависеть от архитектуры вашего
бота и от выбранной библиотеки для взаимодействия с API.

Answer (score 0):

В телеботе это реализуется посредством изменения клавиатуры сообщения, можно и самого сообщения. полистай @testdfffbot. Выбор децствий не работает, тк надо подключать словарь, либо бд, но думаю, этот пример вполне устроит.

вообщем, с простого, просто добавлю комментарии в нужных местах:

```
# создаем клавиатуру для выбора дня недели
def create_days_keyboard():
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Понедельник', callback_data='monday'),
               types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Вторник', callback_data='tuesday'),
               types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Среда', callback_data='wednesday'),
               types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Четверг', callback_data='thursday'),
               types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Пятница', callback_data='friday'),
               types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Суббота', callback_data='saturday'),
               types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Воскресенье', callback_data='sunday'))
    return markup

# создаем клавиатуру для выбора действий
def create_day_actions_keyboard():
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Добавить задание', callback_data='add_task'),
               types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Удалить задание', callback_data='delete_task'),
               types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Назад', callback_data='back'))
    return markup

# обработчик старта диалога
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message_handler(message):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='Выберите день недели', reply_markup=create_days_keyboard())

# обработчик нажатия кнопок выбора дня недели
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data in ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday'])
def day_callback_handler(call):
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text=f'Выбран {call.data}', reply_markup=create_day_actions_keyboard())

# обработчик нажатия кнопки Назад
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'back')
def back_callback_handler(call):
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text='Выберите день недели', reply_markup=create_days_keyboard())

# обработчик текстовых сообщений
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def text_message_handler(message):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='Выберите день недели', reply_markup=create_days_keyboard())
```

Comment: вас не смутило, перед тем как давать ответ, что вопросу более 6 лет? даже того бота, на который ссылался автор в вопросе уже не существует

Comment: Вопрос открыт, значит что требует ответа, логично?

Comment: может он открыт по той причине, что автору этого вопроса уже не нужен ответ или он попросту не пользуется данным ресурсом? за него закрыть никто не может, вот он и открыт. Вы должны это понимать, раз спрашиваете за "логичность"

Comment: Все может быть.